# Undefined connection string from non browser exposed environment variable MongoDB & NextJS (next-connect)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js, environment-variables, next-connect

I'm having a problem with my mongodb connection string in my nextjs CRUD application in production.
I followed this guide: https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/nextjs-building-modern-applications/

And I read about environment variables here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables Giving me the idea that I should be able to safely store my connection string as an environment variable without exposing it to the browser, given I should only need to use it server side?

It works perfectly fine when I run the application locally. But in production (azure app service) the connection string appears undefined unless I expose it to the browser by adding the "NEXT_PUBLIC_" prefix to the variable.

Is it safe to expose this variable / Is there something I should do differently to make it work without exposing it / Is there another approach that should be taken entirely?

My database.js:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';

const client = new MongoClient(process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

async function database(req, res, next) {
  await client.connect();
  req.dbClient = client;
  req.db = client.db('Loggen');
  return next();
}

const middleware = nextConnect();

middleware.use(database);

export default middleware;
```

Comment: _"the connection string appears undefined unless I expose it to the browser"_ - Then shouldn't you investigate why the variable is being used on the browser? Are you using the database connection anywhere on client-side code? This might indicate there's a problem with how you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not expose `env` variables.

A) create `.env.local` file in your project and [set up local env variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#loading-environment-variables). (normally all env files are ignored: check `gitignore` file)

B) You define your [vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables) `.env` variables (with the same values for connection)

C) As discussed [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/connections-not-closed-with-nextjs/115037), you should follow [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb) example, check how they manage connection (it's an official example), to avoid connection duplication and errors.

D) remember, that your `.env` variables are accessible only server-side. So, if you like, you can transfer them to client-side but it's not recommended

Your `database.js` (in example: mongodb.js) should be:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.mongoApiUrl;
const MONGODB_DB = process.env.MONGODB_DB;

// check the MongoDB URI
if (!MONGODB_URI) {
    throw new Error('Define the MONGODB_URI environmental variable');
}

// check the MongoDB DB
if (!MONGODB_DB) {
    throw new Error('Define the MONGODB_DB environmental variable');
}

let cachedClient = null;
let cachedDb = null;

export async function connectToDatabase() {
    // check the cached.
    if (cachedClient && cachedDb) {
        // load from cache
        return {
            client: cachedClient,
            db: cachedDb,
        };
    }

    // set the connection options
    const opts = {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    };

    // Connect to cluster
    let client = new MongoClient(MONGODB_URI, opts);
    await client.connect();
    let db = client.db(MONGODB_DB);

    // set cache
    cachedClient = client;
    cachedDb = db;

    return {
        client: cachedClient,
        db: cachedDb,
    };
}
```

And better not to use your approach with `next-connect`, it will create big amount of connections.

Comment: B) Yeah I already have my "production env variables" as github secrets and grab them with a github action and docker, is this the equivalent to the vercel stuff you are linking or is it something different?

Comment: A) I use a gitignored .env.local and a non ignored .env that is populated during build time e.g.: DB_USERNAME=$DB_USERNAME